# Assigning a byte array to a variable (has to be primitive)

Tags: c#, codedom

```
var1.InitExpression = new CodePrimitiveExpression(buffer);
```

buffer is a byte[] array. It needs to be a primitive type like just an int/byte. However, I'm assigning it to a codeDom variable. It doesn't work.

I get the invalid primitive error. Consider using CodeObjectCreateExpression.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is.  You can't set it to an array per the documentation for `CodePrimitiveExpression`:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeprimitiveexpression(v=vs.110).aspx -- are you looking for something like `CodeArrayCreateExpression`?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codearraycreateexpression(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah it seems they don't have a way for these things. Serves me right for using an outdated API. I've switched to Roslyn.